# php session not working on other pages

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I'm creating a form which people need to sign in to update, the log in and session redirect work fine. I've tried hundreds of variations on sessions from books and forums non seem to do what I would like, and it seems so simple.
This is the code from the previous page.

```
<?php
include("setting.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_namem";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_namem WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION["myusername"];
$_SESSION["mypassword"];
header("location: login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password Please Try Again";
}
?>
```

I would like to load the the next two pages if the username and password has been validated.

Comment: Try placing `session_start();` on TOP of your pages, rather than further down below. Plus this `$_SESSION["myusername"];` and the other one, aren't doing you any good, if they're not assigned to anything. You could try `$_SESSION["myusername"]=$_POST['myusername']; etc.`

Comment: Can we see the code for the next page?

Comment: I also noticed that you're storing passwords in plain text, a definite `no-no`. That, mixed in with `mysql_*` functions instead of `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO, will equal disaster.

Comment: I can also tell that, you either haven't tested this, or haven't gotten error reporting `ON`. How can I tell? Because, what you presently have, will throw an error such as `headers already sent in...` --- Yet, there is one exception; I'll let you tell me what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(empty($_SESSION['myusername']['mypassword'])) { 
   header("Location: login.php");  
   die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 
$username = $_SESSION['myusername']['mypassword'];
```

Try this at TOP of any next page.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the top of all the pages protected by password:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])){
 header("location: logout.php");
 die();
}
```

I have to tell that your session variables, $_SESSION["myusername"]; and $_SESSION["mypassword"] are empty, give them so values so you can use them eventually.

Create a page logout where you show a logout message and also add:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

That will destroy the sessions and log out the user.

**** Use mysqli, the mysql functions that you are using will be soon be removed from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your session is starting up properly, these lines do diddly-squat:

```
$_SESSION["myusername"];
$_SESSION["mypassword"];
```

You might be referring to an old, outdated, insecure, and *terrible* example that is relying on `register_globals` which has been removed several years ago, deprecated for years before that, and a terrible idea since its inception.

Basically, any time you see something like that where variables just magically are stored/retrieved from a session/get/post/cookie/etc array it means that it's old, insecure, and *wrong*.

You need to actually assign those variables to the `$_SESSION` array, eg:

```
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword;
```

That said, `session_start()` should generally be one of, if not *the*, first lines in each page you create. The function needs to set some HTTP headers in the background, and if you code happens to produce any output before that it will fail to do so, generate warnings, and your sessions won't work at all.